# Error 'Depends: python:any. Unmet dependencies' after installing python 2.7.5

Tags: apt, python

I've installed python 2.7.5 on my ubuntu 14.04. And then I wanted to install virtualbox (or any other app), but I'm getting this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-xapian-index : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 duplicity : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 gconf2 : Depends: python:any
 hplip-data : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ibus : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ibus-pinyin : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ibus-table : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 landscape-client-ui-install : Depends: python:any
 python-apt : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-aptdaemon : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-cairo : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-chardet : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-commandnotfound : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-crypto : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-cupshelpers : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-dbus : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-debian : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-debtagshw : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-defer : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-dirspec : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-gi : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-gobject-2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-gtk2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-httplib2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-ibus : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-imaging : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-libxml2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lockfile : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lxml : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-notify : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-oauthlib : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                   Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-oneconf : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-openssl : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pexpect : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pil : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-piston-mini-client : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pkg-resources : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7)
                        Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-qt4 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-reportlab : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-requests : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-samba : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-serial : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-sip : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-six : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
              Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-smbc : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-twisted-core : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-twisted-web : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-ubuntu-sso-client : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-urllib3 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                  Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-xapian : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-xdg : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-zeitgeist : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-zope.interface : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 sessioninstaller : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 software-center : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 software-center-aptdaemon-plugins : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 totem : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 totem-plugins : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ubuntu-system-service : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 unity : Depends: python:any
 virtualbox : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
              Depends: libgsoap4 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: virtualbox-dkms (>= 4.3.34-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                       virtualbox-source (>= 4.3.34-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                       virtualbox-modules but it is not installable
              Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 4.3.34-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And if I run 'sudo apt-get -f install', all these dependencies will be deleted and my ubuntu will crash (I've already tried it and I've reinstalled ubuntu twice!!). Any ideas?? Help please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python`